# How to use key of getter property in a generic method signature

Tags: typescript

I'd like to define a class whose descendants have a method signature that adapts to a compile-time fixed property, which may be overridden.

For example:

```
class Parent {
  public get config() {
    return {
      foo: 'lorem',
    };
  }

  public access<K extends keyof this['config']>(key: K): this['config'][K] {
    return this.config[key];
  }
}

class Child extends Parent {
  public override get config() {
    return {
      foo: 'lorem',
      bar: 'ipsum',
    };
  }
}

new Parent().access('foo');
new Child().access('bar');
```

This example seems to [*almost* work](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEAKYCcCmA7ALtA3gWAFDWgAcBXAIxAEthoBzJDYAexQDMKaAKASizwIORpiCFL3z8CLRowBc0AOQhGyALbyANH34BfANxbteLSXJVoYYMCRQAPAGloSAB5pUAExgBrJAE9GLaDQACwoIAG15JlZ2eQBdAD4Obx85Oy45YNCIqLYaOLC7WLEJQWFRTIgAOhz2MOTY-XFDXGa8UEgYAGEQkDdHF3cYeGR0YqIySmpGADckBAQKNyRaemgazh4ccQF6MrGJKVkFJVUNLQlSRDl5CkIIYjVNbeg9AzxW3BQkAHc4RFQ0NxKhYrFAOPJDvIuI0vr9uhRekCQdYIODLggobogA), except TypeScript throws a compiler error on `return this.config[key]`:

```
Type 'K' cannot be used to index type '{ foo: string; }'.(2536)
```

But I'm not sure I understand why this is erroring, since `K` is *defined* as being a key of `{foo: string;}`.

NB: I know this could be solved with generics by defining an interface, but I was interested to see if I could DRY this up, and only define the property (and its shape) on the class itself.

Comment: This is the best that i can do [(see playground)](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.5.2#code/MYGwhgzhAEAKYCcCmA7ALtA3gKGtADgK4BGIAlsNAOZIbAD2KAZmVQBQCUWue0yahBCm69eTevQBc0AOQh6yALYyANDzwBfANw8N2HkVIVoYYMCRQAPAGloSAB5pUAExgBrJAE96TaGgAWZBAA2gBEDMysoQC6AHxsAUHS8MjoKtAentLWXDii-ILCiRAAdBEsVMGZJu5ePn6e+Ej1xWHlUdHROprYetigkDAAwoEgznaOLjApqBh5BCTklDR0jBWcIrwFQpui4lKy8kqq6rzEiNIyZPgQhMpqotq6vfooSADucIiznCWm5lA2DJ9jIODo3p8RmQxr9-hYIEDzghQeCPl9UmhYWZ4YjECjsBDoFCYRw-tjATJzgAvFFAA)

Comment: I filed an issue on Github, and apparently this is working as intended: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/46954#issuecomment-983015649

Answer (score 0):

in `K extends keyof this['config']`, the type resolution is deferred. This means that K is of type `{ foo: "lorem" }` in `Parent` class, and of type  `{ foo: "lorem", bar: "ipsum" }` in `Child` class.

In the other hand, the type resolution of `return this.config[key];` is not deferred. This means that the type of `this.config[key]` is always `{ foo: "lorem" }`

In `Parent` class, K is `{ foo: "lorem" }` and `this.config` is of type `{ foo: "lorem" }`, everything is fine. But in `Child` class, K is `{ foo: "lorem", bar: "ipsum" }` and `this.config` is of type `{ foo: "lorem" }`, the types doesn't match. This explains why the compiler emits the following error message:

```
Type 'K' cannot be used to index type '{ foo: string; }'.(2536)
```

You can get more infos in the issue discussion filled by **Alec**: [issue #46954](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/46954#issuecomment-983015649)

The following snippet works only if `Child config` extends the return type of `Parent config`, and use an explicit type casting to make types match.

```
class Parent {
  public get config() {
    return {
      foo: 'lorem',
    };
  }

  public access<K extends keyof this["config"]>(this: Parent, key: K) {
    return this.config[key as keyof typeof this["config"]];
  }
}

class Child extends Parent {
  public get config() {
    return {
      foo: 'lorem',
      bar: 'ipsum',
    };
  }
}

new Parent().access('foo');
new Child().access('bar');
```

[see playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.5.2#code/MYGwhgzhAEAKYCcCmA7ALtA3gKGtADgK4BGIAlsNAOZIbAD2KAZmVQBQCUWue0yahBCm69eTevQBc0AOQh6yALYyANDzwBfANw8N2HkVIVoYYMCRQAPAGloSAB5pUAExgBrJAE96TaGgAWZBAA2gBEDMysoQC6AHxsAUHS8MjoKtAentLWXDii-ILCiRAAdBEsVMGZJu5ePn6e+Ej1xWHlUdHROprYetigkDAAwoEgznaOLjApqBh5BCTklDR0jBWcIrwFQpui4lKy8kqq6rzEiNIyZPgQhMpqotq6vfooSADucIiznCWm5lA2DJ9jIODo3p8RmQxr9-hYIEDzghQeCPl9UmhYWZ4YjECjsBDoFCYRw-tjATJzgAvFFAA)

Comment: I'm aware — I filed the issue. However, the issue doesn't lie in the inheritance: you'll get a compiler warning even without the `Child` class. The issue is that `this['config']` isn't a type, and it adopts the concrete type `{foo: string}`

Comment: I see. You should write an answer. I will remove mine.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [issue I raised](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/46954#issuecomment-983015649), this is working as intended.

Direct copy-paste of RyanCavanaugh's answer:

---

Property access on class fields doesn't get deferred type resolution like you're expecting: the type of this.config is plain `{ foo: string }`, not `this["config"]`. That causes this example to break, but is necessary for other scenarios to work -- otherwise you couldn't write

```
class Parent {
  public config = {
    foo: 'lorem',
  };
  public mut() {
    this.config.foo = "ergo";
  }

  public access<K extends keyof this['config']>(key: K): this['config'][K] {
    return this.config[key];
  }
}
```

since there's no guarantee that the derived type doesn't need a more-specific value of `foo`